# lighttpd web server using raspberry pi failed (duplicate port

Tags: macos, webserver, lighttpd

I am trying to install lighttpd  on my mac. this is the error I encounter:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript lighttpd, action "start" failed.
Failed to start Lighttpd. Maybe another webserver is already listening on port 80?
```

I have 2 ports how do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question, I found this great article on lighttpd:

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-setup-a-web-server-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Hope it helps many others

thanks all:)!